# Can I use two || and one && in the same if statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

You choose two planets A and B in the selector options to measure the distance.

For example:

```
if (($planetA == "Nova Terra" || $planetB == "Nova Iaponia") && ($planetA == "Nova Iaponia" || $planetB == "Nova Terra")) 
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 290 parsecs"; 
}

else if (($planetA == "Nova Terra" || $planetB == "Novo Mars") && ($planetA == "Novo Mars" || $planetB == "Nova Terra"))
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 230 parsecs"; 
}
```

You read "from Nova Terra to Nova Iaponia OR from Nova Iaponia to Nova Terra". To = and.

This is similar to like:

```
if ($planetA == "Nova Terra" || $planetB == "Nova Iaponia") 
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 290 parsecs"; 
}

else if ($planetA == "Nova Iaponia" || $planetB == "Nova Terra") 
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 290 parsecs"; 
}

else if ($planetA == "Nova Terra" || $planetB == "Novo Mars")
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 230 parsecs"; 
}

else if ($planetA == "Novo Mars" || $planetB == "Nova Terra")
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 230 parsecs"; 
}
```

Comment: You "can" do this (it's syntactically valid), but the logic is wrong.  If both planetA and planetB are "Nova Terra", you get the message saying 290 parsecs.

Comment: This is the problem that I am referring. Would the correct logic be to split if into 4 statements? But I want to shorten and economise the codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to interchange your logical operators to get result you want

```
if (($planetA == "Nova Terra" && $planetB == "Nova Iaponia") || ($planetA == "Nova Iaponia" && $planetB == "Nova Terra")) 
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 290 parsecs"; 
}

else if (($planetA == "Nova Terra" && $planetB == "Novo Mars") || ($planetA == "Novo Mars" && $planetB == "Nova Terra"))
{ 
    echo "From $planetA to $planet B: 230 parsecs"; 
}
```